# What would have happened if Voldemort died a natural death?

Tags: harry-potter

According to the answer to [Could Voldemort have died a natural death with his horcruxes intact?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31155/could-voldemort-have-died-a-natural-death-with-his-horcruxes-intact), if Voldemort's natural body were to die he'd be rendered a spirit in need of a body. We see this in Philosopher's Stone, where... well, where this happens. Voldemort accidentally kills his mortal body due to Lily's protection, and his spirit (somehow) flies to Albania, where it, eventually, meets Quirrell.

My question is this: If Voldemort had succeeded, and had lived a long long life with his Horcruxes intact, would his body eventually wither away (due to natural aging), leaving his spirit lost and looking for a way to create a body as in Philosopher's Stone?

---

I'd just like to point out that this ISN'T a duplicate question. The answer to the question I linked clearly states that "even if [someone with a horcrux]'s body is attacked or destroyed, one cannot die". Now we see Voldemort *die*, his Avada Kedavra spell backfired and hit HIM. This reduced him to that "ghost"-like form. My question is asking about the natural death of the body case. Some mentioned that having horcruxes prevents natural death, but that isn't stated anywhere. Horcruxes seem to only prevent death in that they keep the soul "earthbound and undamaged".

Comment: Your question is probably a duplicate of the question you mention, despite it being referenced in your question. The answer to that one states that Voldemort *cannot* die a natural death, and thus that his body cannot “wither away.”

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, added a reason why.

Comment: @user74421 Still dupe. You haven't differentiated this question from the linked question enough. What details are you looking for that isn't in the other question? Both this question and the other are asking about **natural** causes. If those answers don't satisfy what you're looking for, then you can ask for clarification. I agree that the top answer to that question doesn't really mention old age, or illness; however that doesn't mean that you should ask the exact same question again...